# Convert DeviceOrientation data to CMAccelerometer data

Tags: javascript, ios, accelerometer, core-motion, device-orientation

I have an iOS game that uses the tilt percentage of the device as a control. In my iOS app, I'm using CoreMotion's `CMMotionManager.accelerometerData.acceleration` to get a `CMAcceleration` struct and then using the x and y values of that struct for the tilt percentage.

I want to approximate the same behavior in a javascript implementation of my game. I'm trying to using `DeviceOrientation`, but am having trouble mapping the alpha, beta and gamma values into something like the `CMAcceleration` values.

How can I calculate tilt percentage in javascript to get the same values I get from CoreMotion?

Comment: DeviceOrientation might not be what you're looking for. Check out 'devicemotion' — it provides a 3D vector (x,y,z) values that may correspond more closely to CMAcceleration — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceMotionEvent — otherwise there's a handy diagram here describing what the alpha,beta,gamma values mean — http://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/spec-source-orientation.html (you'd have to do some 3D polar->rect conversions to get the right vector)

Comment: Thanks! The `accelerationIncludingGravity` values from `devicemotion` were what I was looking for.